# Run different data sets for each test in a sequence for each iteration using Test NG

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

**Expected behaviour**

The point here that i'm expecting is to iterate the data set for each of the test in sequence for each iteration, in such a way all the tests should run in with first set of data, follows by second until the end

```
public class SampleFactory {
DataGenerators dataGen;

@Factory(dataProvider="dp")
public Object[] createInstances(String country, String email, String firstName, String securityQuestion, String title, String ccyFrom, String ccyTo) {
    return new Object[] {new PersonalRegoTest(country, email, firstName, securityQuestion, title, ccyFrom, ccyTo)};
}

@DataProvider(name="dp")
public static Object[][] dataProvider() {
   // dataGen = new DataGenerators();

    Object[][] dataArray = {
            {"country1", "test@testmail.com","abc", "Model", "Mr", "AUD", "USD"},
            {"country2", "test1@testmail.com","abcd", "Model", "Mr", "USD", "NZD"}
    };
    return dataArray;
}
}
```

And my PersonalRegoTest is as follows

```
public class PersonalRegoTest extends Appium {
PersonalRego personalRego;
DataGenerators dataGen;
String country="";
String email="";
String firstName="";
String securityQuestion="";
String title="";
String ccyFrom="";
String ccyTo="";`

PersonalRegoTest(String country, String email, String firstName, String 
securityQuestion, String title, String ccyFrom, String ccyTo) {
    super();
    this.country = country;
    this.email = email;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.securityQuestion = securityQuestion;
    this.title = title;
    this.ccyFrom = ccyFrom;
    this.ccyTo = ccyTo;
}
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void initialize() throws IOException {
    personalRego = new PersonalRego(driver, System.getProperty("platform"));
    dataGen = new DataGenerators();
}
@Test(priority = 1, alwaysRun=true, description="select of Personal Rego form", groups="personalRego")
public void verifyPersonalRegoPageWindow() {
    personalRego.isPersonalRegoWindowDisplayed();
}
@Test(priority = 2, alwaysRun=true, description = "fill step 1 of Personal Rego form", groups="personalRego")
public void validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage() {
    ...
}
@Test(priority = 3, alwaysRun=true, description = "fill step 2 of Personal Rego form", groups="personalRego", dependsOnMethods = "validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage")
public void validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage() {
    ...
}
@Test(priority = 4, alwaysRun=true, description = "fill step 3 of Personal Rego form", groups="personalRego", dependsOnMethods = {"validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage", "validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage"})
public void validateAndSubmitPersonalRegoForm_ThirdPage() {
   ...
}
@Test(priority = 5, alwaysRun=true, description = "Last step of Personal Rego form to reset app", groups="personalRego", dependsOnMethods = {"validateAndSubmitPersonalRegoForm_ThirdPage"})
public void resetApplication(String reset) {
    System.out.println("reset application ");
    ..
}
```

PFA the similar result as like before. Please advise me if i'm doing something wrong now

**Current problem:**
My tests runs as follows

```
verifyPersonalRegoPageWindow
verifyPersonalRegoPageWindow(1)
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage(1)
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage(1)
..
```

**Expected result**

```
Iteration - 1
verifyPersonalRegoPageWindow
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage
..

Iteration - 2
verifyPersonalRegoPageWindow
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_FirstPage
validateAndCompletePersonalRegoForm_SecondPage
..
```

Can someone please advise as I got struck here?

Comment: Try with group-by-instances. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations

Comment: What difference does it make? Tests should be able to run in any order. The end result is the same, all tests are run.

Comment: @Grasshopper Thanks for your reply. I ran by group-by-instances only.

Answer (score 0):

It was an E2E Tests for countries selected. All that is required is to **remove** the **priority** from each tests and just have `dependOnMethods` which will resolve this issue.